# Why Apache .htaccess rewrites non Latin character URL to urlencoded? How to solve it?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, utf-8, url-rewriting

Why Apache .htaccess rewrites non Latin character URL to urlencoded? How to solve it?

`domain.com//контакты` returns `domain.com/%25d0%25ba%25d0%25be%25d0%25bd%25d1%2582%25d0%25b0%25d0%25ba%25d1%2582%25d1%258b`

`domain.com/контакты//` returns `domain.com/%2525d0%2525ba%2525d0%2525be%2525d0%2525bd%2525d1%252582%2525d0%2525b0%2525d0%2525ba%2525d1%252582%2525d1%25258b/`

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite multiple slashes with single slash after domain
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite multiple slashes with single slash in URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's not gibberish, it's urlencoded.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm mostly agree with @akond. But I've made some tests, you can enforce apache not rewrite the characters in the response by ading the **NE** tag. So your line would be:

```
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

On my first tests I did'nt notice any changes, but in fact it seems **my firefox was already sending 'nice' request with url encoding activated**. So the response was as well url encoded. So I tried with **telnet**:

Without [NE]:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET //контакты HTTP/1.1
Host: myvhost.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 05 Feb 2011 21:14:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.6 with Suhosin-Patch
Location: http://myvhost.com/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b
(.. to be continued ..)
```

With [NE]:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET //контакты HTTP/1.1
Host: myvhost.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 05 Feb 2011 21:12:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.6 with Suhosin-Patch
Location: http://myvhost.com/контакты
(.. to be continued ..)
```

So on the apache side you can do something, but I'm not sure it is really useful :-) most browser will already encode the url before hitting apache. For example this is the 'same request' in the apache access.log from my telnet client and from a firefox:

```
GET //\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b HTTP/1.1
GET /%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me. With `NE` it works on all browsers except IE, where `domain.com//контакты` returns `urlencoded` and `domain.com//контакты//` fine url -> `domain.com/контакты/`. Do you have some idea why it is so?

Comment: without NE, in urlencoded form, it should always work, the question is why don't you want urlencoded form? urlencoding avoids problems with bad browser misunderstanding strange characters.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

That's why. And you cannot change that behaviour.